# I have to develop chatting application for LAN just like file sharing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have to develop chatting application for LAN just like file sharing which technology in .net i have to use. Just like WPF, WCF or simple asp.net web application or mvc framework.

Comment: You did forget to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a chat application by using **Asp.Net SignalR**. It's very easy to build by using this tech. Go through this official link [here](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Or-else you can find many articles about signalR [here.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/technologies/signalr)